# ES6 Display div to none when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm new at ES6 and I'm trying to display to none a div when an inner button is clicked.

I tried this but it's not working:

```js
const hide = () => {
  const z = document.getElementById('button')
  const y = document.getElementById('block')
  z.onclick = () => {
    y.style.display='none'
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <button id="button" onClick="hide()">my button</button>
</div>
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attaching an event handler for first time. After the second time it will work and will again attach an event handler.

You don't need to use inline event handler, avoid this type of event handler attachement. You can just remove the `hide` function part serving the content. When your code runs, it will attach the event handler

```js
const z = document.getElementById('button');
const y = document.getElementById('block');

z.onclick = () => {
    y.style.display = 'none';
};
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <button id="button">my button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hiding the `div`, **your hide method is assigning a new `onclick` handler to your button**.

Simply

```
const hide = () => {
    document.getElementById('block').style.display='none'
  }
```